# Optimising jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly novice at javascript and jquery. I have created the script below which works well with the form I've added it to but it's not optimised. Could anyone suggest ways that I could optimise this script? Thanks for any advice

```
$(function() {

// This button will increment the value
$('#delegates').change(function() {
    $("#d_names p")
        .slice(0)
        .hide();
    var currentVal = $('#delegates').val();
    if (currentVal == 450) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0,-9)
            .fadeIn();
        $('#delegate2').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate3').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate4').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate5').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate6').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
        $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position2').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position3').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position4').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position5').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position6').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
        $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 900) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -8)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate3').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate4').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position3').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position4').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 1350) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -7)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate4').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position4').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 1800) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -6)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position5').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 2250) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -5)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position6').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 2700) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -4)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position7').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 3150) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -3)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position8').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 3600) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -2)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position9').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 4050) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0, -1)
            .fadeIn();
            $('#delegate10').attr('value', '');  
            $('#position10').attr('value', '');  
    } else if (currentVal == 4500) {
        $("#d_names p")
            .slice(0)
            .fadeIn();
    }

    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('#sub')
            .val(currentVal)
            .formatCurrency({
            region: 'en-GB'
        });
        $('#vat')
            .val((currentVal) / 100 * 20)
            .formatCurrency({
            region: 'en-GB'
        });
        $('#total')
            .val((currentVal) * 1.2)
            .formatCurrency({
            region: 'en-GB'
        });
       $('.sub').html((currentVal)).formatCurrency({region: 'en-GB'});
       $('.vat').html((currentVal)/100 * 20 ).formatCurrency({region: 'en-GB'});
       $('.total').html((currentVal) * 1.2 ).formatCurrency({region: 'en-GB'});



    } else {
        $('#sub')
            .val(0);
        $('#vat')
            .val(0);
        $('#total')
            .val(0);
    }


});


});
```

**HTML**

```
    <p class="selectq"><select name="numbers" id="delegates">
          <option value="">Places required</option>
          <option value="450">1</option><option value="900" >2</option><option value="1350">3</option>
          <option value="1800">4</option>
          <option value="2250">5</option>
          <option value="2700">6</option>
          <option value="3150">7</option>
          <option value="3600">8</option>
          <option value="4050">9</option>
          <option value="4500">10</option>
   </select></p>
         <p>Delegate names (£450+VAT per delegate):</p>
          <p class="regs"><span>Name</span>Position</p>
<div id="d_names">
              <p><label for="delegate1">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate1" size="20" name="delegate1"  />
              <label for="position1">Position</label><input type="text" id="position1" size="20" name="position1"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate2">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate2" size="20" name="delegate2"  />
              <label for="position2">Position</label><input type="text" id="position2" size="20" name="position2"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate3">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate3" size="20" name="delegate3"  />
              <label for="position3">Position</label><input type="text" id="position3" size="20" name="position3"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate4">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate4" size="20" name="delegate4"  />
              <label for="position4">Position</label><input type="text" id="position4" size="20" name="position4"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate5">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate5" size="20" name="delegate5"  />
              <label for="position5">Position</label><input type="text" id="position5" size="20" name="position5"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate6">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate6" size="20" name="delegate6"  />
              <label for="position6">Position</label><input type="text" id="position6" size="20" name="position6"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate7">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate7" size="20" name="delegate7"  />
              <label for="position7">Position</label><input type="text" id="position7" size="20" name="position7"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate8">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate8" size="20" name="delegate8"  />
              <label for="position8">Position</label><input type="text" id="position8" size="20" name="position8"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate9">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate9" size="20" name="delegate9"  />
              <label for="position9">Position</label><input type="text" id="position9" size="20" name="position9"  /></p>
            <p><label for="delegate10">Name</label><input type="text" id="delegate10" size="20" name="delegate10"  />
              <label for="position10">Position</label><input type="text" id="position10" size="20" name="position10"  />
          </p>

      </div>
      <br class="clearfloat"><p class="price">Subtotal: <span class="sub"></span></p>
      <p class="price">VAT: <span class="vat"></span></p>
      <p class="price">Total: <span class="total"></span></p>
       <input type="hidden" name="sub"  id="sub" value=""/><input type="hidden" name="vat"  id="vat" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="total"  id="total"  value=""/>
```

Comment: Group elements together by giving them a common class, then select by that class. `$(".myclass").val("");`. You can get a subset of the class result using `.slice()`, like `$(".myclass").slice(2).val("");`

Comment: Can we see how your HTML is structured to give a more educated suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $("#d_names p").hide();
    $('#delegates').change(function () {
        var sel = $('#delegates option:not(:first):selected').index();
        if (sel > 0) {
            $('#d_names p').hide().slice(0, sel).show().end().slice(sel, 10).find('input').val('');
        } else {
            $('#d_names p').find('input').val('').end().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/T6Nsa/1/)

Comment: Wow! thanks that's much more streamline and makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do comma seperated

$("#delegate1,#delegate2,...,...,..").attr("value","");

Answer (score 0):

The way to optimize this is to keep your selectors to a minimum. Try not to create unnecessary jQuery objects.

Group your inputs into classes, hide all inputs on change and then show the group you want to show based on the select value.

```
var that = $(this);
if (currentVal === 450) {
    that.find('div').hasClass('450').fadeIn();
} else if (currentVal === 900) {
   that.find('div').hasClass('450').fadeIn();
   that.find('div').hasClass('900').fadeIn();
}
```